# Why is ptr = (int*)12 and *ptr = 42 bad programming in C?

Tags: c

There is a C code and the I want to know where's a bad part.

```
int main() {
    // PART A
    int a = 12;
    printf("%p\n", &a);
    int *ptr = &a;
    *ptr = 15;
    printf("%i\n", a);
    // PART B: something bad starts
    ptr = (int*)12;
    *ptr = 42;
    printf("%i\n", *ptr);
}
```

In PART (B), Why is ptr = (int*)12 and *ptr = 42 bad programming in C?

Comment: `ptr is now a pointer that points to int 12.` no, ptr points to address 12, which is prohibited from modifications

Comment: The program has undefined behavior when it evaluates `printf("%f\n", &a)` since `%f` means that the argument needs to be a `double`, but you are actually providing an `int *`.

Comment: The title could be more specific, but I wouldn't downvote it: it is well formed and pointers might take some time to grasp for someone with different language background.

Comment: If you are using memory mapped hardware where location 12 is a device register and you want to write 42 to that device register, then the "Something bad" part is quite valid.

Comment: @HAruMOmo "Why is this bad programming in C?" It is a bad programming in C because the barces are placed incorrectly!:)

Comment: @Lashane Isn't (int*) a pointer?

Comment: @HAruMOmo no, in this case it is cast from value to pointer, maybe you wanted to get address of variable, but it is `&` operator and it cannot be used on const values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with

```
ptr = (int*)12;
*ptr = 42;
```

is it is writing to a location that may belongs to program or operating system. If the address `12` belongs to the program then it will behave erratically. If it belongs to operating system then program most likely will crash.

Comment: Is **ptr** the same thing as ***ptr**?

Comment: No. `ptr` is a pointer while `*ptr` is an alias to which memory address `ptr` is pointing.

Comment: What do you mean by alias?

Comment: alias means another name of that location.

Comment: Thank you! I am still a little confused. So here, (1) how do we know **(int*)12** is a memory address? (2) What does (int*) do here? (3) Why is  `*ptr = 42;` bad as well?

Comment: `(int *)` is a cast to `12` to make it a memory address. `*ptr = 42;` is bad because it is writing to a location which may belongs to the program or operating system as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @HAruMOmo I can try to break it down for you; `(int*)` means points-to an int, so `(int*)12` means address 12 points-to an int, so `ptr = (int*)12` means address ptr equals 12 which points-to an int, so `*ptr = 42` means the int at ptr equals 42, this is bad because you told ptr it points-to an int at address 12 and you most probably shouldn't write data to that location.

Comment: @James Oh. Thank you! So to double check, `ptr = (int*)12;` is trying to do something that we don't even know whether it even exists or we may not have an access to it, and that's why it is breaking? Also for `*ptr = 42;` is also bad because it is trying to write something we have problem with?

Comment: Thank you!! But.. could you specify what you meant by **program** or **operating system** if possible?

Comment: Program means the code you are running, i.e. the above posted code in your question. By operating system I mean the os on which you are running this program.

Comment: @HAruMOmo It's likely that the address exists, what it points to or if you would have access to it i'm not sure, if it points to your PC's lower memory which i suspected, that's memory usually used for something important like an interrupt vector table or the bios, things you wouldn't want to even try to overwrite.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is:

```
ptr = (int*)12; // This will assign memory address 0x0000000C (12) to ptr
```

You are trying to assign memory address to a pointer without knowing whether it exist or not. The program may crash here.

Also : 
    `printf("%f\n", &a);` ← it should be `"%p"`

Comment: Also all the declarations mixed with the code, are not good in c, they are valid of course, but I believe that the code is easier to read if one separates declarations from code.

Comment: More strictly `printf("%p\n", (void*)&a);`

Comment: It would probably crash at `*ptr = 42` wouldn't it?

Comment: @James, may be it will, may be not ... Now @[haccks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29593290/1983495) explained it.